# What is wrong with my asp.net web service call

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I am attempting to consume a web service method from jquery and i get this error below

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

which is pointing to my service method url. Here is my code below,

```
$("#btnDialog").click(function () {
    var test = $("#hfID").val();
    testService(test);
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
});

function testService(test) {
    $.ajax({
        crossDomain: true,
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:64461/Service1.asmx?op=HelloWorld",
        data: test,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(json) {
            $("#lblID").text(json.responseText);
        },
        failure: function(response) {
            alert("Did not work");
        }
    });
}
```

and the web serive method is

```
public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld(string id)
    {
        string toReturn = null;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        {
            toReturn = "recieved but nothing";
        }
        else
        {
            Class1 class1 = new Class1();
            class1.GetName();
            toReturn = class1.GetName();
        }
        return toReturn;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it should be a POST type call in jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function testService(test) {
$.ajax({
    crossDomain: true,
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:64461/Service1.asmx/HelloWorld",
   data: "{'id':'" + test + "'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(json) {
        $("#lblID").text(json.responseText);
    },
    failure: function(response) {
        alert("Did not work");
    }
 });
}
```

Comment: I previously tried that but i get this error with that solution and still does not work. Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html

Comment: Make sure that your web service can be called by javascript.   [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService] public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService

Comment: its using System.Web.Script.Services;... and that is already in there

Answer (score 0):

Your `[WebMethod]` attribute tells the endpoint to return XML.

Your JS code is asking for JSON and expecting a JSONP response. Hence there's an invalid token in the response, namely the first `<` of the XML.

One option is to deal with the XML instead of expecting JSON.

Another option is to include the `ScriptMethod` attribute on along with the `WebMethod` attribute so that you can control the response.

`[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]`